# How to draw a polygon using EaselJS?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, easeljs

There are `Shape.graphic` methods to draw circles and rectangles easily, but no obvious method to draw polygons such as hexagons and polygons?  How do you draw them using EaselJS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually its very simple, one just needs to use the method `moveTo` and `lineTo`.  An example to draw a simple triangle,

```
var polygon = new createjs.Shape();
polygon.graphics.beginStroke("black");
polygon.graphics.moveTo(0, 60).lineTo(60, 60).lineTo(30, 90).lineTo(0, 60);
```

And come to think of it, there is no need of a `drawPolygon` method.  It won't be used that extensively in my opinion.

Comment: Can we fill this createjs.Shape with color ?

Answer (score 9):

I was surprised this functionality was missing, so I went ahead and wrote it.

```js
(createjs.Graphics.Polygon = function(x, y, points) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.points = points;
}).prototype.exec = function(ctx) {
    var start = this.points[0];
    ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    this.points.slice(1).forEach(function(point) {
        ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    });
    ctx.lineTo(start.x, start.y);
}
createjs.Graphics.prototype.drawPolygon = function(x, y, args) {
    var points = [];
    if (Array.isArray(args)) {
        args.forEach(function(point) {
            point = Array.isArray(point) ? {x:point[0], y:point[1]} : point;
            points.push(point);
        });
    } else {
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(2);
        var x = null;
        args.forEach(function(val) {
            if (x == null) {
                x = val;
            } else {
                points.push({x: x, y: val});
                x = null;
            }
        });
    }
    return this.append(new createjs.Graphics.Polygon(x, y, points));
}
```

This will add a `drawPolygon()` method to the graphics object that can be called in 3 ways.

Points as separate arguments `drawPolygon(x, y, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, ...)`

Points as an array of arrays `drawPolygon(x, y, [[p1x, p1y], [p2x, p2y], ...])`

Points as an array of objects `drawPolygon(x, y, [{x:p1x,y:p1y}, {x:p2x,y:p2y}, ...])`

Eg:

```
poly1.graphics.beginFill("Red").drawPolygon(0,0,10,10,10,40,40,30,60,5,30,0);
poly2.graphics.beginFill("Green").drawPolygon(0,0,[[10, 10], [10, 40], [40, 30], [60, 5], [30,0]]);
poly3.graphics.beginFill("Blue").drawPolygon(0,0,[{x:10,y:10}, {x:10,y:40}, {x:40,y:30}, {x:60,y:0}]);
```

See a working fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/k3rgk11e/2/

Answer (score 7):

There is a `drawPolyStar` method, which you can use to draw geometric shapes.
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html#method_drawPolyStar

Anything irregular you can use the Shape `lineTo` and `moveTo` methods as mentioned by @quik_silv earlier (remember to begin a stroke or fill first before drawing).

3rd party tools can export more complex shapes, such as Flash CC (using the Toolkit for CreateJS, or the new Canvas document). The DrawScript plugin for Illustrator makes it really easy to export Illustrator paths to CreateJS, including the compact format. http://drawscri.pt/

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

## The simplest way is to draw a [PolyStar](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.PolyStar.html)

#### JS Code:

```
x=60, y=60, size=20, sides=3, angle=0;

polygon = new createjs.Shape();
polygon.graphics.beginFill("black").drawPolyStar(x, y, size, sides, 0, angle);

myCanvas.addChild(polygon);
```

#### Result:

[image: triangle by easeljs]

<sub>Change the value of `sides` for making any polygon. You may also rotate the shape using `angle`.</sub>